# Alternative way to submit temp html table in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I always use the hard coded way for submitting temp table in MVC 
Ex: I have to submit the following temp table after Jquery manipulating

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GridSumbit", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table class="Vista" id="table1">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                           col 1
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                           col 2
                                        </th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Jquery

```
function AddRow(val1,val2) {
            var col1 = '<input name="col1" type="hidden" value="' + val1 + '" />';
            var col2 = '<input name="col2" type="hidden" value="' + val2 + '" />';
            $('#table1 tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + col1 + '</td><td>' + val2 + '</td></tr>');
        }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GridSumbit(List<GridRows> grid)
        {

.....
```

Model

```
public class GridRows {

public string col1 {set;get;}
public string col2 {set;get;}

}
```

Is there an alternative way to do this ? more organized way...

Comment: Is it inside a form ? what is  the definition of `GridRows` ?

Comment: Yes its inside a form i'll edit the question

Comment: GridRows contains 2 properties  (col1,col2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For model binder to correctly map the form data to your action method parameter, which is a list of `GridRow` class, your form element's `name` attribute value should be like

`[{index}].col1`

*where `{index}` is the **zero** based index.*

So if you are adding 2 rows, your inputs should be like this

```
<input name="[0].col1" type="hidden" value="a" />
<input name="[0].col2" type="hidden" value="b" />

<input name="[1].col1" type="hidden" value="c" />
<input name="[1].col2" type="hidden" value="d" />
```

You can do this by fixing your `AddRow` method. Here is a simple solution where i am reading the table row length and using that to derive the index. Based upon your HTML markup/client side code, make adjustments to this. All you need is the correct name attribute value in the above format.

```
function AddRow(val1, val2) {
    var index = $('#table1 tr').length-1;
    var col1 = '<input name="[' + index+'].col1" type="text" value="' + val1 + '" />';
    var col2 = '<input name="[' + index +'].col2" type="text" value="' + val2 + '" />';
    $('#table1 tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + col1 + '</td><td>' + col2 + '</td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great I'll try it ,But is there an alternative way or formal way in MVC to do this functionality ?

Comment: for model binder to work, you need to have your name attribute values follow the expected format. When you add inputs in client side, this is how you do it ( assuming you are not using a client side mvc framework like angular/vue js). Another option is to make an ajax call to server where it will return a partial view result for the markup needed

Comment: Thanks this help me a lot  :)